# Как создать двумерный массив numpy с определенной размерностью?

Tags: python, numpy

Никак не могу понять как создать массив с определенной размерностью, вот что я имею ввиду, вот как я создаю сейчас:

```
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

И мне немного сложно понимать что как тут работает(т.к. до это с массивами работал в с++ а там по другому)

Я так понял что мы в приведенной строке создаем в массиве две строки с разными значениями, так вот мой вопрос, а как можно создать определенное кол-во строк по переменной? 
Например пользователь ввел число 5 и нам создался массив с 5ю строками, в ручную же для каждого случая не пропишешь, или может можно как то добавлять новые строки к существующему?

Почитал документацию не очень разобрался в методе append и в значении "axis". Помогите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Comment: Из той же документации, задать размерность массива: ```np.array([1, 2, 3], ndmin=2)```

Comment: @Nobody отправьте ссылку пожалуйста может я не ту какую то версию смотрю

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

Comment: @Nobody этот параметр добавляет что то не то, мне нужно что бы добавлялось вот так [][,[],[] а он зачем то вот так [[[[]]]], создает вокруг того и не понятно как к этим элементам обращаться

Comment: @Nobody Это как бы оборачивает массив в слои типо на вашем же примере: если просто написать в array([1,2,3]) то вывод массива будет [1,2,3] а если написать с ndmin = 2 то вывод будет  [[1,2,3]], он оборачивает это типо в какой то еще непонятный для меня слой, а как добавить именно строки? типо [1,2,3][5,3,9]?

Comment: Посмотрите метод *reshape*

Comment: Я так понял вам массив определенного размера создать нужно? numpy.ones, numpy.zeros. Оба первым принимают аргумент shape, которым является (rows, columns).

Comment: Чем должен быть заполнен созданный массив?

Comment: @ShamusRezol спасибо попробую

Comment: @MaxU числами одного типа(может float, может int)

Comment: В numpy не очень часто возникает необходимость заранее создавать пустой массив, чтобы позже его заполнять. Поэтому советую вам более подробно описать для чего вы пытаетесь создать данный массив, как и чем вы его планируете заполнять и как использовать. Это позволит дать ответ, который будет наиболее полезен именно вам и именно для вашего случая

Comment: @MaxU у меня простое как кажется задание(если бы мне сказали в с++ сделать это было бы легко) мне сказали что пользователь вводит размер массива по столбцам и строкам, создается массив, и затем нужно произвести с ним определенные действия

Comment: Пользователь вводит только  размер массива или также его элементы? Как производится ввод элементов?

Comment: Работая с numpy нужно научиться мыслить векторно - это когда мы делаем мат. операции над векторами и матрицами целиком, вместо того, чтобы писать вложенные циклы и обрабатывать по одному элементу за итерацию цикла

Comment: пользователь вначале вводит размер а потом элементы если я смогу так создать массив то ввод будет осуществляться во вложенном цикле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy

''' numpy.ones(shape, dtype)
    @shape, tuple - размер массива вида (rows, columns).
    @dtype - тип элементов. Может быть numpy.uint8, uint32, float, u3, ..... .

    p.s Осторожней с типами. К примеру при uint8, если значение превышает 1 байт (8 бит),
    то оно становится примерно вида value % 2**8
'''
""" 
    Пустой массив с 4 строчками по 8 столбцов, где каждый элемент равен одному:
"""
ones=numpy.ones((4, 8), numpy.uint8)

print(ones)

""" Подобно работает zeros. Думаю, разница очевидна.
"""

""" Первый элемент будет равен трем, а не 259 (256 + 3) так как тип numpy.uint8.
"""
ones[0, 0]=2**8 + 3
print(ones)
```